# How to improve quality of mp3 output after applying filters?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to increase the pitch of a mp3 file while more or less preserving the same tempo:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=0.8,asetrate=44100*1.3" output.mp3
```

It works, but the quality of the output is slightly worse than the original.

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked ChatGPT, and after some changes, I found out this changes the pitch without affecting the quality of the output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "rubberband=pitch=1.3" output.mp3
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how good the algorithms in ffmpeg are, but you're pushing that a long way, slowing to 80% then pitching up 1/3 of an octave. You're trying roughly, to 'invent' 20% more data, then reduce it again by 30%. That's likely to get pretty crunchy.

Maybe try the free trial of [Amazing Slow Downer](https://www.ronimusic.com/amsldowin.htm) which isn't the absolute best algorithm in the world, but it's a pretty good one & very simple to use. The trial possibly won't let you save the result, unlike the paid version, but you can test how the various algorithms work [it has 5 different methods to choose from] & see if it can do any better.

If you want to stick with ffmpeg, you might do better first upconverting to 88.2kHz 32-bit WAV [this will be a *big* file], process that, then downconvert to regular mp3 afterwards.
This does not *gain* you any sound quality in itself, but gives any processing algorithm more room to play with.

Completely by coincidence I found a list of 'slow downer' apps on Music.SE - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/123/software-that-slows-down-music-to-help-in-transcribing

Comment: I'd expect `Audacity` (free) to be able to do similar things as at least ffmpeg (last paragraph) above, maybe with some more effort though. Based on experience from image-processing, a downsample generally achieves a better result if done last; so try to upsample (`asetrate=44100*1.3`) FIRST.

Comment: @Hannu, here with audacity: https://crumplepop.com/how-to-change-pitch-in-audacity-in-few-steps/